Expo React Native app build apk on android keeps killing a socket io port
I have react native app with expo, running on Android, during the development with expo the socket client can connect and communicate with the server on python. When I build the apk and test it on the phone, there is never a connection.
The client and the server both are on the same network.
This is my client on the react native
import { Socket } from 'socket.io-client';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

class SocketClient {
    private static instance: SocketClient;
    private socket: Socket;
    public port = 5000;

    private constructor(name: String) {
        // Initialize the socket connection
        if (name.includes("1"))
            this.port = 5001;
        else if (name.includes("2"))
            this.port = 5002;
        else if (name.includes("3"))
            this.port = 5003;
        else if (name.includes("4"))
            this.port = 5004;

        this.socket = io('http://192.168.1.56:' + this.port, { transports: ['websocket'] });
    }

    public static getInstance(name: String): SocketClient {
        // if (!SocketClient.instance) {
        SocketClient.instance = new SocketClient(name);
        // }
        return SocketClient.instance;
    }

    public connect(): void {
        this.socket.connect();
    }

    public disconnect(): void {
        this.socket.disconnect();
    }

    public emitEvent(eventName: string, data: any): void {
        console.log(`Emitting event: ${eventName} with data: ${JSON.stringify(data)} to port ${this.port}`);
        this.socket.emit(eventName, data);
    }
}

// const socketClient = SocketClient.getInstance();
export { SocketClient };

And I called like this
  const socketClient = SocketClient.getInstance(selectedPrinter.name);
    socketClient.connect();
    socketClient.emitEvent("print", {
      file: path,
      printer: selectedPrinter.name,
    });


I had found that is the http instead of https that androids kill even before it begins. Now my problem is a bad request version and not getting the right event fire but a bunch of hex codes
